# How can we visualize kubernetes objects/topology in a graph?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Is it possible to visualize kubernetes topology and see it update on-the-fly as objects are added/deleted/linked?

I saw a video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38SNQPhsGBk where service/pods show up as icons on a graph. For example, see

[image]

I am new to kubernetes and have installed minikube. How do I visualize my cluster's topology? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options but the one I like most is [Weave Scope](https://www.weave.works/oss/scope/) where you get visualizations such as:

[image: Weave scope screen shot]
<sub>(source: [contentstack.io](https://images.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blt300387d93dabf50e/blt94bf2945b508e588/5b8fb098fffba0957b6ea7e6/download))</sub>